# How to reduce the memory usage during Python program execution

Tags: python, gpu

I have some questions about memory usage in my program. When I run a file-reading program, the file size is only 100MB, but the memory usage of my process shows as 1.6GB (I haven't set any additional variables and have only imported the necessary library files). I understand that there are many other things that are also stored in memory during program execution, but I would like to know if there is any way to reduce them. The same thing happens when I transfer variables to the GPU, and my GPU shows usage of 600MB.

code

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import time
import struct

if __name__ == "__main__":
    graphEdge = []
    boundList = []

    file_path = "./../../srcList.bin"
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            data = file.read(4)
            if not data:
                break
            integer = struct.unpack('i', data)[0]
            graphEdge.append(integer)


    file_path = "./../../range.bin"
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            data = file.read(4)
            if not data:
                break
            integer = struct.unpack('i', data)[0]
            boundList.append(integer)

    graphEdge = torch.Tensor(graphEdge).to(torch.int).to('cuda:0')
    boundList = torch.Tensor(boundList).to(torch.int).to('cuda:0')
    memory_size = graphEdge.element_size() * graphEdge.numel()
    print(f"Tensor memory: {memory_size/(1024*1024)} MB")
```

Comment: When i had problems like you describe on past I solved using "yield". Here can you start to investigate https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-generator

Comment: How large is memory usage without the torch stuff? And what does `print([len(graphEdge), len(set(graphEdge)), len(boundList), len(set(boundList))])` say?

Comment: Maybe you can check in a more accurate way the total memory used by using [torch.cuda.mem_get_info()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.mem_get_info.html#torch.cuda.mem_get_info)

It returns a tuple where the first element is the free memory usage and the second is the total available memory.

Comment: Hello, based on your request, this is the result I output in the terminal.`[29856864, 589563, 590129, 578208]`

Comment: Which input file is 100MB? Please be specific! In any case, 100MB would become 25M integer objects, each of which occupies one to four pointer-sizes (educated guess), plus one pointer to hold the reference in the list. One pointer would be 8B for modern 64 Bit hardware. So, the increase would be factor 4 to factor 10, just for loading into Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 32-bit number as a Python `int` object takes 32 **bytes**. Plus 8 bytes for the list's reference to it. So 4 bytes in the file takes 40 bytes in memory as Python list+ints.

You commented that `graphEdge` has 29,856,864 numbers, but only 589,563 *different* ones. So you have many duplicates and you can save a lot of memory by not storing separate `int` objects with the same value. Use only one object per different value, and use that object repeatedly. One way to do that is with a dictionary that maps each value to its object. Do `intern = {}.setdefault` at the start, and then append like this:

```
graphEdge.append(intern(integer, integer))
```

The dictionary of course also takes extra memory, but it saves a lot more than it costs. I estimate it'll overall take 800 MB less.

See [interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interning_%28computer_science%29?wprov=sfla1) at Wikipedia.

You could save even more if you didn't create a `list` of `int` objects but a Python or NumPy `array` of 32-bit ints, but I'm not familiar with Torch and what it accepts as input.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the size of your program you can try to use any other small-size int variable eg. `int16` or `int8` instead of a 32-bit size integer, if the data can be adjusted in these datatypes.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I would like to understand why, even if I store my variables using the int32 data type, the size of my variables should only be 100MB, yet my process occupies nearly 2GB of memory. There seems to be a significant discrepancy between them.

Comment: How did you came to the conclusion that it needs to be 100Mb?
The problem is that you don't exactly "load" the file into memory if that how you came to the conclusion, python creates a buffer with the content of the file, but this one is used to create python data structures and types that are not equivalent to a plain text file.

Comment: Yes, I made the judgment based on the size of the file directly. I understand that the buffer size may not be equivalent to the size of the plain text. However, if there is a 10x difference between them (120MB vs 1.2GB), there might be room for optimization.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if in this case can help a lot, but in other cases it helps to use the garbage collector of python to free space from variables than won't be used later.

You can try that by using it before you measure the memory to check if it makes any difference:

```py
    import gc

    ...
   
    gc.collect()

    graphEdge = torch.Tensor(graphEdge).to(torch.int).to('cuda:0')
    boundList = torch.Tensor(boundList).to(torch.int).to('cuda:0')
    memory_size = graphEdge.element_size() * graphEdge.numel()
    print(f"Tensor memory: {memory_size/(1024*1024)} MB")
```